# Как правильно написать запрос SQL? Тестовое задание

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос

Выполняю тестовое задание, застопорился в конце...

Есть [описание бд](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QIxrAFCSboVlZ3QTU4LTVsaUE/view).

Нужно написать запросы:

1. Выбрать преподавателей, у которых по результатам собеседования ни один студент не устроился на работу
2. Посчитать преподавателей на каждой кафедре, участвовавших в собеседованиях, где по результатам собеседования ни один студент не трудоустроился.

Никак не соображу... если не трудно, подскажите :)

Comment: Что именно не получается? Я сомневаюсь, что кто-то будет писать все 0, если ты не представишь наработок...

Comment: Расскажите, какие идеи насчёт пути решения, что уже попробовали, какие похожие задачи уже решали, что смущает или не укладывается в голове.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

> Выбрать преподавателей, у которых по результатам собеседования ни один
>   студент не устроился на работу

```
SELECT *
FROM Lecturer
WHERE id NOT IN
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT lect_id
    FROM Var_Assignment
    )
```

> Посчитать преподавателей на каждой кафедре, участвовавших в
>   собеседованиях, где по результатам собеседования ни один студент не
>   трудоустроился.

```
SELECT sf.id, sf.name, count(lect.id)
FROM Sub_Faculty sf LEFT JOIN Lecturer lect ON sf.id = lect.sub_fact_id
WHERE lect.id NOT IN
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT lect_id
    FROM Var_Assignment
    )
GROUP BY sf.id, sf.name
```